# flutter app not fetching home page data from wordpress website?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

i am working on a news application project which needs to fetch and display data from website as soon as it gets any new posts updated to any category listed over there.

i have built the app without issues or warnings but still when ever i open the app on mobile device its just loading , nothing showing only one category is being fetched and rest all the categories are displayed but data not showing within app nor giving any errors can somebody tell me what is going wrong here ???

i have attached build gradle below...

```js
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"



def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.*****.news"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           debuggable true
           renderscriptDebuggable true
           jniDebuggable true
           minifyEnabled true
       }
   }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk true
        includeInBundle true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
    ndkVersion '24.0.8215888'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```js
[
  {
    "repositoryUrl": "https://packages.jetbrains.team/maven/p/ij/intellij-redist",
    "artifacts": [
      {
        "groupId": "junit",
        "artifactId": "junit",
        "annotations": {
          "[4.0, 5.0)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.junit",
            "artifactId": "junit",
            "version": "4.12-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.hamcrest",
        "artifactId": "hamcrest-core",
        "annotations": {
          "[1.0, 1.3)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.org.hamcrest",
            "artifactId": "hamcrest-core",
            "version": "1.3-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core",
        "artifactId": "jackson-core",
        "annotations": {
          "[2.0, 3.0)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.com.fasterxml.jackson.core",
            "artifactId": "jackson-core",
            "version": "2.9.6-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core",
        "artifactId": "jackson-databind",
        "annotations": {
          "[2.0, 3.0)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.com.fasterxml.jackson.core",
            "artifactId": "jackson-databind",
            "version": "2.9.6-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.miglayout",
        "artifactId": "miglayout-swing",
        "annotations": {
          "[5.0, 5.1]": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.com.miglayout",
            "artifactId": "miglayout-swing",
            "version": "5.1-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "io.netty",
        "artifactId": "netty-buffer",
        "annotations": {
          "[4.0, 4.2)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.io.netty",
            "artifactId": "netty-buffer",
            "version": "4.1.27.Final-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "io.netty",
        "artifactId": "netty-common",
        "annotations": {
          "[4.0, 4.2)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.io.netty",
            "artifactId": "netty-common",
            "version": "4.1.27.Final-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "io.netty",
        "artifactId": "netty-resolver",
        "annotations": {
          "[4.0, 4.2)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.io.netty",
            "artifactId": "netty-resolver",
            "version": "4.1.27.Final-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "io.netty",
        "artifactId": "netty-transport",
        "annotations": {
          "[4.0, 4.2)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.io.netty",
            "artifactId": "netty-transport",
            "version": "4.1.27.Final-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.picocontainer",
        "artifactId": "picocontainer",
        "annotations": {
          "[1.0, 1.2]": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.org.picocontainer",
            "artifactId": "picocontainer",
            "version": "1.2-an1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.yaml",
        "artifactId": "snakeyaml",
        "annotations": {
          "[1.20, 1.3)": {
            "groupId": "org.jetbrains.externalAnnotations.org.yaml",
            "artifactId": "snakeyaml",
            "version": "1.23-an1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.Log;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  private static final String TAG = "GeneratedPluginRegistrant";
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin better_player, com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.analytics.FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_analytics, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.analytics.FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_core, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_messaging, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.InAppWebViewFlutterPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_inappwebview, com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.InAppWebViewFlutterPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new dev.vbonnet.flutterwebbrowser.FlutterWebBrowserPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_web_browser, dev.vbonnet.flutterwebbrowser.FlutterWebBrowserPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.github.ponnamkarthik.toast.fluttertoast.FlutterToastPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin fluttertoast, io.github.ponnamkarthik.toast.fluttertoast.FlutterToastPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin google_mobile_ads, io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.iyaffle.launchreview.LaunchReviewPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin launch_review, com.iyaffle.launchreview.LaunchReviewPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.packageinfo.PackageInfoPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin package_info, io.flutter.plugins.packageinfo.PackageInfoPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin path_provider_android, io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.share.SharePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin share, io.flutter.plugins.share.SharePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin shared_preferences_android, io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin sqflite, com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin url_launcher_android, io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.videoplayer.VideoPlayerPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin video_player_android, io.flutter.plugins.videoplayer.VideoPlayerPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new creativemaybeno.wakelock.WakelockPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin wakelock, creativemaybeno.wakelock.WakelockPlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.WebViewFlutterPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin webview_flutter_android, io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.WebViewFlutterPlugin", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: App is writing in Flutter or Kotlin?
Show also your java/kotlin file content

Comment: app is written using flutter ....

Comment: Where do you fetch and display that data?

Comment: on target device where we install the application....!

Comment: yep, but can you show file where is code with fetching and display that data?

Answer (score 0):

WebView is working in debugging mode because it has internet permissions in the android/app/src/debug/androidManifest.xml file

You need to add the same in android/app/src/main/androidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I hope it works well.

All the best.